# The View is not passing the correct information to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Probably the fix of this should be something simple, but I just cant find whats wrong and I have to explain my scenario in order for readers to understand.

I have a Class called Position, another Applicant, Another ApplicantPosition, another Status and ApplicantPositionHistory

The class Position holds basic info like position name: eg: .net developer.
The class Applicant holds basic info like name, first name,etc.
The class ApplicantPosition holds the relationship, last modified date and CURRENTSTATUS.
The class ApplicantPositionHistory has 2 references to status one called newStatus and oldStatus.

```
public class ApplicationPositionHistory
{


  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ApplicationPositionHistoryID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ApplicantPositionID")]
public ApplicantPosition ApplicantPosition { get; set; }

[Column("ApplicantPositionID")]
public int ApplicantPositionID { get; set; }

[Column("OldStatusID")]
public int OldStatusID { get; set; }

[Column("NewStatusID")]
public int NewStatusID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("OldStatusID")]
public Status OldStatus { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("NewStatusID")]
public Status NewStatus { get; set; }

[StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Comments  should not be longer than 500 characters.")]
[Display(Name = "Comments")]
public string Comments { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

In my front end, I have one screen that shows the applicants that have applied to a position

```
name   position            actions
andew   .net developer     view history

When they click on history they see:
old status     new status      comments         datemodified
new            applied         new prospect
applied        approved by hr  approved by hr
```

The problem in in the screen where they create Entities of ApplicantPositionHistory.
I want to use the newStatus from the last row as the oldstatus, and the newstatus should be the one that the user selects. (Here is the key of the entire question)

In the code below, newStatus and OldStatus are always pointing to the same ID. So the Insertion works, but its always using the same ID and not showing a real tracking of the statuses history of an applicant.

This is the HTML

```
<table>    
    <tr>
        <th>
            Previous Status
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.Label(ViewData["oldStatus"].ToString())
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ApplicationPositionHistory</legend>       
        <div class="editor-label">
            New Status
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("NewStatusID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Statuses)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewStatusID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

This is the controller action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ApplicationPositionHistory applicationpositionhistory)
        {
            applicationpositionhistory.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                applicationpositionhistory.OldStatusID = applicationpositionhistory.NewStatusID;
                applicationpositionhistory.OldStatus =
                    _unitOfWork.StatusRepository.GetStatusById(applicationpositionhistory.NewStatusID);

                _unitOfWork.ApplicantPositionHistoryRepository.InsertApplicationPositionHistory(applicationpositionhistory);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("History", new { applicantPositionID = ViewData["applicantPositionId"] });  
            }

            ViewBag.oldStatusID = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.StatusRepository.GetAllStatus(), "StatusID", "status", applicationpositionhistory.OldStatusID);
            ViewBag.newStatusID = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.StatusRepository.GetAllStatus(), "StatusID", "status", applicationpositionhistory.NewStatusID);
            return View(applicationpositionhistory);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question...two options could be:

1-) Create a hidden field in the form that has the value of OldStatus. You would set this in the model/viewModel in HttpGet action. Thus when the form is posted, the OldStatus will be bound.

2-) In the controller in the Create [HttpPost] action, instead of:

```
applicationpositionhistory.OldStatusID = applicationpositionhistory.NewStatusID;
```

Lookup in your datastore/service what the most recent Status is and set it. I think this would be preferable as you won't have to worry about advanced users that can modify your hidden field.

On a side note, I would consider creating a domain class that encapsulates this logic rather than having controller need to worry about it.

HTH...

Answer (score 2):

ViewData only exists during that request. It does not span requests.

One way of handling this would be using the `HiddenFor()` helper.  This will allow you to create a hidden field with the `OldStatusID` which you can read on you next post.